# can i conditionally "merge" a Single with an Observable?

Tags: rx-java2

i'm a RxJava newcomer, and i'm having some trouble wrapping my head around how to do the following.

- i'm using Retrofit to invoke a network request that returns me a `Single<Foo>`, which is the type i ultimately want to consume via my *Subscriber* instance (call it `SingleFooSubscriber`)
- `Foo` has an internal property `items` typed as `List<String>`.
- if `Foo.items` is not empty, i would like to invoke separate, concurrent network requests for each of its values. (the actual results of these requests are inconsequential for `SingleFooSubscriber` as the results will be cached externally).
- `SingleFooSubscriber.onComplete()` should be invoked only when `Foo` and all `Foo.items` have been fetched.

fetchFooCall
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())

```
// Approach #1...
// the idea here would be to "merge" the results of both streams into a single
// reactive type, but i'm not sure how this would work given that the item emissions
// could be far greater than one. using zip here i don't think it would every 
// complete.

.flatMap { foo ->
    if(foo.items.isNotEmpty()) {
        Observable.zip(
                Observable.fromIterable(foo.items),
                Observable.just(foo),
                { source1, source2 -> 
                    // hmmmm...
                }
        ).toSingle()

    } else {
        Single.just(foo)
    }
}

// ...or Approach #2...
// i think this would result in the streams for Foo and items being handled sequentially,
// which is not really ideal because
// 1) i think it would entail nested streams (i get the feeling i should be using flatMap 
//    instead)
// 2) and i'm not sure SingleFooSubscriber.onComplete() would depend on the completion of
//    the stream for items

.doOnSuccess { data ->
    if(data.items.isNotEmpty()) {
        // hmmmm...
    }
}

.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(
    { data  -> /* onSuccess() */ },
    { error -> /* onError()   */ }
)
```

any thoughts on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated!

bonus points: in trying to come up with a solution to this, i've begun to question the decision to use the `Single` reactive type vs the `Observable` reactive type. most (all, except this one `Foo.items` case?) of my streams actually revolve around consuming a single instance of something, so i leaned toward Single to represent my streams as i thought it would add some semantic clarity around the code. anybody have any general guidance around when to use one vs the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to nest `flatMap`s and then convert back to `Single`:

```
retrofit.getMainObject()
  .flatMap(v ->
     Flowable.fromIterable(v.items)
       .flatMap(w ->
         retrofit.getItem(w.id).doOnNext(x -> w.property = x)
       )
       .ignoreElements()
       .toSingle(v)
)
```

Comment: hadn't yet seen/used `ignoreElements()`. if this is enabled, is it guaranteed that every element will have been "processed" to completion before the onComplete listener is called? in other words, in my specific case, i'm asking if the remote call for each `item` will have completed, or could they potentially still be in-flight at the time the onComplete listener is invoked?

Comment: IgnoreElements is there to ignore *all* elements and complete when the source completes. That means no in-flight elements.